# Adding alias of an App or actual App onto the right side of Dock

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, dock, preferences

[image: How do I do add an app placed on the right side of the Dock as shown?]

How do I do add an app placed on the right side of the Dock as shown?  (On the right of the line separator, along with the Downloads and Trash icons).

This is on a Macbook Air 2015 running Mac OS Catalina, I had this machine since the default OS on Macbook Air 2015.  *Probably* added the app icon there during Mac OS Mojave.

Reason for asking is that I remember actually adding MacVim.app onto the position as shown but forgot how to duplicate this.  I don't believe I used any non-native stuff to do this.

If anyone knows a better place to ask this question, please tell me.

Thanks.